# Error CSRF token mismatch in docker environment using a laravel application

Tags: laravel, docker

I have a laravel application running in docker locally on my windows machine. Everything is working correctly. But every time a post request is triggered the following error "CSRF token mismatch" appears. Remembering that every request that is made, the token is sent according to the Laravel documentation. Does anyone have a tip on what it could be?

To try to solve the problem, I have already edited the env in the variable SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false and I have already checked the server's time zone

Comment: Do you mean to say that GET requests are running fine but it's just POST request giving the error?

Answer (score 0):

The docs are huge, hence god knows what "according to Laravel documentation" means.

But in my case, I simply pass `_token` parameter for any non-GET request, like:

```
example.com/?_token=my-token
```